# Future for an alternative plan + I'm afraid

Tags: future-constructions

> Are you coming with us tomorrow to the beach?

Intended answer is: "No. I prefer going to the mountain."

1. I'm afraid I'll be going to the mountain.
2. I'm afraid I will go to the mountain.
3. I'm afraid I'm going to the mountain

I would use 1. Right? What about 2. and 3.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find (3) the most natural - or, more explicitly

> I'm afraid I've arranged to go to the mountains with [person/group].

(We use *mountain* to refer to a particular one, but *mountains* to mean an area of mountain scenery.)

*I'm afraid I will [verb]* sounds as though you are literally afraid that you will end up doing something unpleasant.